# Use 'r' while reading a file

Tags: python-3.x

Stuck in a silly situation.

A variable has a path name and trying to open it .

```
file_path = 'C:\Users\ARC\Desktop\A3\wordlist1.txt'
f = open(file_path)
```

This gives error : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape (, line 1)

Obviously , using an 'r' in front of file name solves this . i.e

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\ARC\Desktop\A3\wordlist1.txt')
```

Now , how do i append the 'r' with a variable? Or if there is another way? I am thinking 
if an 'execute' statement can be used in some way? I am trying this with Python 3

Answer (score 0):

`r` tells the Python interpreter that the string is to be interpreted as a raw string (i.e. don't process escapes). This is obviously useful when you have escaped strings hardcoded in your source code, but if you get your path from an external source (e.g. read it from a file), you don't need to bother with `r` at all.